# Cannot initialize Shopify API Library. Missing values for: hostName in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, shopify

I am working with "shopify" and "nodejs",Right now i am trying to integrate "shopify module" in nodejs,But i am getting following error

```
"ShopifyError: Cannot initialize Shopify API Library. Missing values for: hostName"
```

Here is my config.js code (node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/lib/config.js",Is this hostname right or where can i get hostname ? why i am getting error "missing hostname" ?

```
var config = {
        apiKey: '',
        apiSecretKey: '',
        scopes: new scopes_1.AuthScopes([]),
        hostName: 'https://partners.shopify.com/xxxxx/stores',
        hostScheme: 'https',
        apiVersion: types_1.LATEST_API_VERSION,
        isEmbeddedApp: true,
        isPrivateApp: false,
        logger: {
            log: defaultLogFunction,
            level: types_1.LogSeverity.Info,
            httpRequests: false,
            timestamps: false,
        },
    };
```

Comment: Did you add the `/xxxxx/` to hide your URL or is it written like that in your code? If so, then you probably have to change that part to your specific URL.

Comment: @Geshode I write that for hide url but actually i passed "shopify partner url" , but i am not sure is this right or not

Comment: Did you edit this file `node_modules/@shopify/shopify-api/lib/config.js` ? You do not need to modify the Shopify lib in node_modules. You need to import the `shopifyApi` function in your code and pass config object.

Answer (score 2):

I had a this issue when attempting `npm run serve` (the default command for production environment with their Docker configuration). In my case, the .env was missing a `HOST` field.

[Shopify Docs say `HOST` is required](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/deployment/web#step-3-set-environment-variables). This was tricky to diagnose because:

1. Shopify doesn't create a HOST field in the env by default
2. Shopify doesn't parse/validate the ENV up front
3. Shopify's error message directs developer to a node_modules file
4. [Shopify renames `HOST` to `hostName` in their code](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/blob/7377761bd60223f73c320e05a0e3f0ab7b0176a9/packages/shopify-app-express/src/index.ts#L101)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error using `npm run dev` as suggested by the [Shopify docs](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create).

I resolved the issue by using the [Shopify CLI](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/commands#dev). To start the dev server you can use the command `npm run shopify app dev`